# Add textbox values to a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am creating text boxes dynamically. I want to take those text box values and store them in a session so i can then store them in a database. How can i do this?

So, the way i am storing the DYNAMICALLY created textbox values is this way.

```
List<Control> _controlsList;
controlsList = new List<Control>();     // object holds the controls
```

Now, in my function i am adding them this way. Keep in mind i have 3+ textboxes

```
if (i < _applicant.Fields.Count)
                _applicant.AddAnswer((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
            else
                _application.AddAnswer((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
            _sessions.ApplicationSession = ((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
           // Session["TextboxValue"] = ((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
```

I have a session class

```
 public class JobApplicantSession
 {

   // public JobApplication ApplicationSession
    public string ApplicationSession
    {

      get {if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] != null)
              // return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
                 return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
           return null; }

      set{ HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = value; }
    }


}
```

I can add then but when i retrieve them from another class i only get the last added textbox. I need to be able to loop through  so i can add those textbox values to a database but i cant loop through an object

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"]; //will get last textbox value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your session class like

```
public class JobApplicantSession
 {

   // public JobApplication ApplicationSession
    public string ApplicationSession
    {

      get {   if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] == null)
              HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = new List<string>();
           return (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
      }

    }


}
```

and add answer to list

```
 _sessions.ApplicationSession.Add((_controlsList[i] as TextBox).Text);
```

you can loop now..

```
foreach(string answer in _sessions.ApplicationSession )
{
...
}
```

Comment: How would i retrieve them in another class? loop through them so i can add them to a database?

Comment: I was able to do this: List<string> result = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];

Comment: it's correct too but using wrapper class like JobApplicantSession is more elegant way.

Comment: should i then use string builder to make a string query so i can add those to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a complex object in the `Session` bucket that you can add and remove from. In your case, you could theoretically just store the `List<Control>` in session and then convert it back to List when you want to add / remove from it.

However, I will point out, there is probably a much better way of doing what you seem to be trying to do. Session is carried across pages throughout the app; this seems to be a more localized data persistence problem, which means you should either be using the database to keep track of the temp state, or you should use ViewState.

Comment: how can i use viewstate? Dont i dd it like i do a session s then i have the same problem?

Comment: Correct, `ViewState` will function similarly to `Session`, except the storage is localized to just this page, which is better. You will still need to modify your code to not simply overwrite the last value written, for example, by making the object stored a `List<>` and then adding to that object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store them in your session in some kind of list structure.

```
var values = new List<string>();
// add each text box value to the list.

HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = values;

//To get them back
var retrieved = HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] as List<string>;
```

You may have to play with the data type you use a little bit, some don't serialize well.